# Is there a positive integer $d$ in existence$?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratics, integers, square-numbers

> Suppose there are three positive integers $a,b,c$ such that the product of
> any two is one less than an integer squared, i.e.,
> $$\begin{align}
> ab+1=x^2\\
> ac+1=y^2\\
> bc+1=z^2
> \end{align}$$
> Then is it true that there exists a fourth positive integer $d$ such that its product with any
> of the first three is also one less than a square, i.e.
> $$\begin{align}
> ad+1=w^2\\
> bd+1=u^2\\
> cd+1=v^2
> \end{align}$$

I tried factorizing the expressions but it did not prove to be of much help. Like we can say that $ab=(x+1)(x-1)$ and similarly for all expressions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

A triplet satisfying $(a,b,c)$ is $(1,3,8)$ and the value of $d$ in this case is $120$. As far as I know, this is an old and very interesting problem and many famous mathematicians had attacked this problem but I guess none of them gave a detailed proof or maybe I don't know about it.

Comment: Why do you believe this to be the case?  Is there some context for the problem?  Have you tried any examples?

Comment: @lulu edited......

Comment: Can you provide some references?  I have not seen this problem before...

Comment: For $(3,5,16)$ one solution is $d=1008$.  Interesting that one needs to go out so far...

Comment: @lulu well, i have seen this problem while I was surfing through internet but unfortunately i forgot to save the link....that's why I asked it here

Comment: @lulu **one needs to go out so far** maybe that's why its very interesting

Comment: I suppose I'd start by asking if $d$ existed for *any* triple $(a,b,c)$, ignoring the constraints.  If there are obstructions there, then one could ask if your constraints proved that these obstructions must vanish for your triples.

Comment: @lulu if this is true then there should exist a parametric solution...can you find that$?$

Comment: I would not assume that simple closed formulas exist here, but who knows?  References would help.  If "many famous mathematicians" have attacked this problem, that would tend to suggest that short solutions aren't available, though, again, anything is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will prove helpful, but I would begin with the observation $a^2b^2c^2=(x^2-1)(y^2-1)(z^2-1)$ to generate $a,b,c$ triples and then use those as the basis to look for $d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this is a classical topic in number theory. In the terminology you're seeking, you're asking whether every "Diophantine triple" of positive integers can be extended to a "Diophantine quadruple" of positive integers. And the answer is yes: Arkin, Hoggatt, and Strauss proved in 1979 that (in your notation) you can choose
$$
d = a + b + c + 2abc + 2xyz.
$$
(It was a well-known conjecture in this field, for example, that there do not exist any Diophantine quintuples of positive integers; this was only proved recently, by He, Togbé, and Ziegler in 2019.)

Comment: so this means that there is no exact proof given by Arkin, Hoggatt and Strauss$?$

Comment: Yes they proved it; edited to clarify

Comment: do you know the proof they gave?

Comment: see https://arxiv.org/html/math/9903035. This terminology should give you the tools you need to learn more on your own.

Comment: thanks............

Comment: @Greg Martin.-If you hadn't given your answer, I would have spent a lot of time (in vain, I think) trying to find one. Thanks.